# Convert jfloatarray to float*

Tags: c, java-native-interface, converters

I've this function in JNI, a wrapper that call WebRtcNs_Process. WebRtcNs_Process receive float*, so how i can convert jfloatArray to float* ?

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
 nativeNsProcess
 (JNIEnv *env, jclass jclazz, jint nsHandler, const jfloatArray input_frame, jfloatArray out) {

//get handle
NsHandle* NS_instance = (NsHandle*) nsHandler;

if (NS_instance == NULL)
    return -1;
int ret;

if (input_frame == NULL || out == NULL)
    return -1;

//create native floats from java floats
jfloat* native_input_frame = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, input_frame,
        NULL);

jfloat* native_output_frame = (*env)->GetFloatArrayElements(env, out, NULL);

//noise suppression
ret = WebRtcNs_Process(NS_instance, native_input_frame, NULL,
        native_output_frame, NULL);

//cleanup and return
(*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, input_frame, native_input_frame, 0);

(*env)->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(env, out, native_output_frame, 0);

return ret;

}
```

Comment: You mean _"How do I convert a `jfloat*` to a `float*`"_ ? Because you already seem to have obtained `jfloat*`s into your arrays. `jfloat` is defined as `typedef float jfloat`, so you've already got the `float*`s you need.

Comment: So there aren't any errors in the code? Because this function returns always -1, but not for a Null pointer and so i thought was a conversion problem, from float[] in java to float*